# DevExpress LookupEdit with multilevel

Tags: devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I am using DevExpress to develop WinForm application .
 Now , I was in trouble with using LookupEdit. Suppose I have a datatable with 3 columns (maybe 2 or 4),column 2 need be filled by selected value in column1,column 3 need be filled by seleced value i column2...Can anyone help me ??

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is very unclear. Can you give an example? Are you using a lookupedit in each column in the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.
I think I understand your question :)

Please look at this example from the Devex site:

[How to filter a second LookUp column based on a first LookUp column's value](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A237)

Comment: It's so kind of you. Thank you.